# Is it possible to reprocess Outlook 2016 emails and run them through the spam filter?

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I recently converted to Outlook 2016 from another email application.  I would like to process all those emails and have them go through the Junk Mail filter.

If I have to write an add-in to do it, that's fine, however, I didn't see anything in the documentation that would indicate how I can access the built in Junk Mail filter.

Comment: The stored emails were already processed by the spam filter. Why do you need to check them anew?

Answer (score 0):

Some junk email options are stored either in the registry or the user's Exchange mailbox, but you can only read blocked senders, domains, etc.  For obvious security reasons you can't set many settings with code.  Redemption offers a method to read/write the stuff that is accessible, see: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdojunkemailoptions.htm

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. However, you can create a VBA macro or COM add-in for checking the stored items against Junk Mail settings configured in Outlook. You may find the [Configure junk email settings in Outlook 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179183.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.